# Cannot display a game centre leaderboard from OpenGL game loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, opengl-es, game-center

I have an OpenGL ios application which I have built on top of the framework used in the tutorials on 71squared.com

All the views, states, controls are state managed within the application, and there is only one UIViewController.

The basic game loop structure is as follows;

GameAppDelegate - this holds the UIView glView, and launches it in applicationDidFinishLaunching as follows;

```
[glView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mainGameLoop) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

GLView contains the mainGameLoop method, and is derived from UIView

The main game loop does the following, as well as creating then releasing an auto release pool and managing a frame counter;

```
while(true)
{
[gameController updateScene];
[self drawView];
}
```

gameController is a UIViewController derived class.

drawView does the following;

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFrameBufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFrameBuffer);
[gameController renderScene];

glBindRenderBufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderBuffer);
[context presentRenderBuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

OKAY... this is all fine.

However, I am trying to display a game centre leaderboard, which just doesnt do anything. I have a feeling I may need to manage the state and do something a little different in the render loop when the leaderboard is presented. The following code is my UIViewController gameController;

```
GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewControler alloc] init];
gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
[self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**The code runs, but doesn't display anything, the game loop just continues. Why not?**

**EDIT:**

Tried triggering the main game loop via both NSTimer and CADisplayLink with no success, presentViewController still does not appear.

Comment: Are you seriously have `while(true)` in your code for updateScene? That maybe why you can't see leaderboard, because it takes full main thread.

Comment: @SAKrisT how about suggesting an answer/alternative? If I knew the problem why would I post it on StackOverflow?

Comment: Its not a duplicate question just because answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your problem is that main thread is always busy with `while(true)`.

I want suggest you, next time, to use GLKit. It's much simple and template in Xcode has everything what you need for simple application.

In current situation you need create loop for drawing and it has 2 different ways:
1. create CADisplayLink - which is better, [here you can grab code](https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/blob/master/Simple%20OpenGL%20ES%202.0%20Example/Classes/GLView.m)

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(mainGameLoop)];
[displayLink setFrameInterval:2];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

2. simple create NSTimer with interval, which is will call mainGameLoop each iteration, but it's not so perfect solution

Here you can find some interesting, Jeff Lamarche has a lot of good tutorials and explanations
https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.ie/

Comment: So would an NSTimer replace the while true loop?

Comment: I am looking to implement CADisplayLink, but the selector is main game loop? Main game loop contains the while(true) loop. SO how would this be any different?

Comment: you need delete while(true)

Comment: Used the timer as I already had an implementation of it lurking in my project, the leaderboard still doesn't show.

Comment: okay... I have now tried triggering the main game loop using CADisplayLink and it works. Animation has become slow as hell but exactly the same result when attempting to call presentViewController to display game centre leaderboard. Same result with all 3 game loop methods.

Comment: next step, it's you need write logic to make pause for rendering. with GLKit it's much easy, because it already has CADisplayLink inside of GLKViewController and implemented pause, and others features which may will need you.

Comment: i tried triggering the leaderboard view code before the game loop, and... nothing! hmmm.

Comment: are you sure? show leaderboard and then place breakpoint in main game loop to see if it entering. you need pause/stop CADisplayLink before showing controller and then resume/recreate drawing loop.

Comment: I disabled main game loop so that all the app should do is boot, authenticate game center, load leaderboard. My application delegate contains a Window and a view, and the init creates the view and adds it to the window. I'm going to have a play with this tonight.